# git merge .idea/workspace error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm relatively new to programming, I've been working with ruby on rails because I'm interested in web development so I figured it was a good thing to start with.

I've been using git to keep the version all tidy, and I've read everywhere that it's a good habit to get into, but it's been flaking on me lately. I know it's user error, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong and how to get it fixed.

I was working on a branch off of the master, called layout, made a bunch of changes, and merged it with the master branch. When I went back to the master branch, the changes didn't seem to commit and I lost a day's worth of work. So I've since just kept a backup folder on my desktop in case it happens again.

I go back to my layout branch, redo all the changes I made, commit it, switch back to master and use

```
git merge layout
```

it gives me this error:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .idea/workspace.xml
```

The only thing I can seem to do that doesn't delete all these files is to continue working on the layout branch. Obviously I don't want this because it's not the 'proper' way to do things.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're using RubyMine.  Make sure you include .idea in your git ignore files.

add this: `.idea/` to your .gitignore file

of course once the files are already tracked with git you need to untrack them.  `git rm <file_name>`